# Voltage for RGB Strip Lighting

Tags: led, low-voltage

I'm looking at building a hobby project featuring led strips. I'm looking at 5v RGB addressable LED strips [The Strips](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GYDLJ24). I've already more or less figured out how much I need to cut for each section and the total power consumption. Each strip that needs to be cut is < 1 meter in length. In total I am going to have 12 strips. No strip will be longer than 1m individually, but there are 2 sections where the total of the strips in that section will be longer than a meter. What do I need to to to ensure each section has the appropriate power?

Comment: This question belongs in electronics.se.  The maker is not helping you very much.  You need to go pull the datasheet for the WS2812 device and figure out how much current it needs in worst-case scenario, then multiply by the number of devices.

Answer (score 0):

65 mA or so per led for 100% all on white, 30 leds per meter, 1.8 Amps per meter. At 12 strips we are talking about  21.6 Amps at 5V or 108 Watts.